# How to get the CSS-Code and save in a String?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am trying to get the code of a CSS-File and save it into a String for later use. I already found something which could do the trick in another post, but nothing I tried was working.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "css/style.css", 
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(cssText) { 
    } 
});
```

Can anyone help and tell me how to get and save the CSS-Code?

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) API. Tells you right there.

```
var myData;
$.get( "your_css.css", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    myData = data;
}); 
console.log(myData);
```

Just a warning, due to JavaScript's nature, line 6 may fire off before line 3. Just food for thought.

**EDIT**

I know the `console.log(myData);` responds null. I meant it to. I was teaching him that if he does this, make sure that if the data is being manipulated anymore, either force it sync or put it in the callback. A better choice would be to put it in the callback.

Comment: `console.log(myData);` must be in callback of get function. If you want to return data. Actually console.log return null.

Comment: @HorsSujet did you not read my answer? I said that in my post. Good god does no one read anymore?

Comment: I read but why do you do this ? It's delusory and console.log will be always call before.

Comment: @HorsSujet because I was letting him know to be aware of the async nature of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting proper css as response then try using below function :

```
$.ajax({ 
url: "css/style.css", 
dataType: "text",
success: function(cssText) { 
    // paste styles to head       
     $('<style type="text/css"></style>').html(cssText).appendTo("head");
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can add stylesheet, and disable it with attribute.

```
var href = "style.css";
$("head").append("<link id='Iwait' type='text/css' href='"+href+"' attribute>");
```

When you want to use your stylesheet, remove disabled attribute :

```
$("#Iwait").prop('disabled', false);
```